# SQL Query searching Strings in Foreign Languages?

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g, amazon-redshift

Is there a SQL function out there in the world that would allow you to search for strings in a specific language? I.E. A query that would only return results in with Japanese characters in it. The data sets I'm working with has varying length strings with multiple different languages in it. I'm using both Redshift, PostgreSQL, and  Oracle 11.1.

Comment: Is this oracle or postgresql? If it is both, you should specify it on your question.

Comment: For Oracle, the answer would likely depend on which character set is used.  Hopefully data is stored in UTF8?

Comment: Yes, Oracle is UTF8.